# Make background-color overlap background-image without extra HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Today I'm wondering on how I can get `background-color` to overlap `background-image` when using `rgba`, with a lower opacity value.  But when I try this in FireFox, the image overlaps the color.  I'll show you (below) exactly what I tried:

```
div {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x300");
   background-color: rgba(0,0,200,0.5);
}
```

I'd like it to give a blue tint over the image, but it just shows the background and no blue at all...  Here is a image result of the div:

[image]

But the desired effect should look like this (below):

[image]

How would I get this desired effect without using any extra HTML in the process?

---

`EXTRA`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TzRCv/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element for the color.

```
#result {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x300");

  /* Other stuff */
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  position: relative;
}

#result:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,200,0.5);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/TzRCv/3/)**

Comment: Okay, thanks.  i didn't think it would be this easy.